Get file from remote Linux server
Scenario:
I have access to a linux server A whose credentials are managed via a PAM server. I want to copy a file to this server from a remote server B whose credentials i have.
Challenge:
SCP from server B to copy files to server A wont work as i don't have the credentials to server A.
Problem:
Server A and B are part of a restricted network meaning the only way to get these files to server A is only from server B.
Question:
Is there a way to fetch the files from server A prompting for credentials for server B.

SCP suggests ssh ... so, you would need to login on one and scp to/from the other ... so you would need credentials of some sort on both - that's how security works

It sounds like you don’t have credentials to the server, you will need to acquire an account, so you can access the server from the original server you currently have access to

Got two solution to this from a friend, let me share for future reference
Solution one: SCP
Fetches the file from the remote server using scp command using the remote server credentials
example
scp userb@192.168.100.2:/home/myuserB/archive* /home/usera/
will copy all the archive files in the servers 192.168.100.2 home/myuserB/ directory to the /home/usera/ directory. This will prompt for userb credentials

Solution two: rsync
Using rsync to schronise files between two directories. This is great especially for large files.
Command
rsync -avz userb@192.168.100.2:/home/myuserB/archive* /home/usera/
Does the same as the above command for scp. Tried both solution on my RHEL 9.4 server and worked okay.

Thank for the responses upon realizing the solution its looks so simple but clearly the situation was overcomplicated by the restrictions.

@WilfredMuhia please post that as an answer, not as a comment

Well noted @SathyajithBhat let me update with the solution.

Got two solution to this from a friend, let me share for future reference
Solution one: SCP
Fetches the file from the remote server using scp command using the remote server credentials, you can get more details from the link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scp-command-in-linux-with-examples/
example
scp userb@192.168.100.2:/home/myuserB/archive* /home/usera/
will copy all the archive files in the servers 192.168.100.2 home/myuserB/ directory to the /home/usera/ directory. This will prompt for userb credentials
Solution two: rsync
Using rsync to schronise files between two directories. This is great especially for large files. Refer to the link below for additional details https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-rsync-to-sync-local-and-remote-directories
Command
rsync -avz userb@192.168.100.2:/home/myuserB/archive* /home/usera/
Does the same as the above command for scp. Tried both solution on my RHEL 9.4 server and worked okay.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
